# If $X\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda)$, then $\textbf{E}(X^{n}) = \displaystyle n\textbf{E}(X^{n-1})/\lambda$

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, exponential-distribution

If $X\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda)$, then $\textbf{E}(X^{n}) = \displaystyle n\textbf{E}(X^{n-1})/\lambda$

**MY SOLUTION**

According to definition of $k$-th moment, we have
\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}(X^{n}) & = \int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{n}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\mathrm{d}x = -x^{n}e^{-\lambda x}\biggr|_{0}^{+\infty} + \int_{0}^{+\infty}nx^{n-1}e^{-\lambda x}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = 0 + \frac{n}{\lambda}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{n-1}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\mathrm{d}x = \frac{n}{\lambda}\textbf{E}(X^{n-1})
\end{align*}

Could someone provide an alternative proof based on moment generating functions or any other technique? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MGF of the exponential distribution is 
$$ M(t) = \mathbb E[e^{tX}] = \frac{1}{1-t/\lambda},\ t < \lambda$$
(which, if you don't want to take as "known", you can get by an easy integration).
This has Maclaurin series
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \mathbb t^j E[X^j]/j! = M(t) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty (t/\lambda)^j $$
which says $$\mathbb E[X^j] = j!/\lambda^j$$
so that for $n \ge 1$
$$ \frac{\mathbb E[X^{n}]}{\mathbb E[X^{n-1}]} = \frac{n! \lambda^{n-1}}{(n-1)! \lambda^{n}}
 = \frac{n}{\lambda}$$